# HTML 5 media player ( OSM PLAYER) customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, media-player

I have implemenetd osm player. I need to customize it. ie When clicking a button (button provided by osm palyer) I need to pause it. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myplayer = "";
 myplayer = $(function() {
    $("video").osmplayer({
      width: '100%',
      height: '600px'
    });

$("button").click(function() {

    myplayer.stop();
})
  });
</script>
<video src="http://progressive.totaleclips.com.edgesuite.net/105/e105598_257.mp4" poster="http://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/143/MPW-71686"></video>
```

Comment: open the console, and try to run methods on the myplayer object from there. The console will give you autofill. My guess is that there will be something like myplayer.pause(), but you will need to test that. I haven't used osmplayer

Comment: I was tested; but it fails ...

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is pause the underlying video tag. so to do that, you will need to get `var video = $('video')[0]` or give it an id and get it with `var video = $('#id-of-video')`

then just do `video.pause();`

you can do this in one step like so:

```
$('video')[0].pause();
```